# Getting Comments into Dashboard Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hey I am creating a blog with rails, my first app. I am trying to make comments that have to be approved first via a dashboard. This is my code currently.

The posts controller

```
 class PostsController < ApplicationController

    before_filter :authorize, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy, :create, :new]

    def index
      @posts = Post.where(:state => "published").order("created_at DESC")
    end

    def new
        @post = Post.new
    end

    def show
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        redirect_to_good_slug(@post) and return if bad_slug?(@post)
    end

    def create
        @post = Post.new(post_params)

        if @post.save
            redirect_to dashboard_path
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        if @post.update(params[:post].permit(:title, :text, :author, :short, :photo, :state))
            redirect_to dashboard_path
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        @post.destroy

        redirect_to dashboard_path
    end

    private
      def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text, :author, :short, :photo, :state)
      end
end
```

The Dashboard Controller

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController

before_filter :authorize, only: [:index]

def index
    @posts = Post.order("created_at DESC")
end

end
```

The comments controller

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

before_filter :authorize, only: [:destroy]

def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment =
    @post.comments.create(comments_params)
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
end

def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
end

private
    def comments_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:commenter, :body)
    end
end
```

The comment Model

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :post
end
```

and finally the routes

```
 resources :dashboard
 resources :posts do
  resources :comments
 end
```

again, I am pretty new to backend dev and ruby, so if need be I can provide more info. I think if I can pull all comments into the dashboard I would be able to figure the rest out.

Thanks!

Comment: Just a side not but I would change `@post.update(@params[:post].permit(etc))` to `@post.update(post_params)`.  Keep your code DRY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to create a `Dashboard` controller that users with access to approve can access.  For the `index` action you can do something like.

```
def index
  @posts = Post.find(approved: false)
end
```

You can also add a scope to the `Post` model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :approved, -> {where(approved: false)}
end
```

You can then just do

```
def index
  @posts = Post.approved
end
```

Comment: I have the posts displaying in the dashboard, but for the life of me I can't get the comments pulled into the view. I can currently do all the post crud within the dashboard. Edit/delete posts and in the edit view I already have it set up to handle draft/publish states. Just no luck getting the comments pulled into the actual dashboard view. Is this what that refers to?

Comment: I added the current dashboard controller to the original post. I think what I need to be able to do is dump all comments that are unapproved into the dashboard view and then from there I can delete or approve them as they come in.

Comment: You should be able to reference it directly off of the post object as post.comments.

Comment: When I try adding post.comments to the view/dashboard/index I get this error <ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_Comment:0x4a4a998>

Comment: You can also do @comments = Comment.where(id: @posts.map{|post| post.id})